# incremental least squares differing with only one row

Tags: matrix, machine-learning, data-mining, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I have to solve multiple least squares problem sequentially - that is one by one. Every least square problem from the previous one changes by only one row. The right hand side is same for all. For eg., Problem 1 : ||Ax-b|| and Problem 2 : ||Cy-b|| where C and A changes by only one row. That is, it is equivalent to deleting a row from A and including a new row in A. When solving problem 2, I also have x. Is there a fast way for solving y of Problem 2?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [Sherman-Morrison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) formula.

The key piece of the linear regression solution is computing the inverse of `A'A`.

If `b` is the old row from `A` and `a` is the new row in `C`, then

`C'C=A'A-bb'+aa'=A'A+(a-b)(a+b)'`

This expression can be plugged into the Sherman-Morrison formula to compute (C'C)^{-1} given (A'A)^{-1}.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer may be NO...

Changing one row of a matrix will lead to completely different spectrum of the matrix. All the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are changed with both magnitude and orientation. As a result, the gradient of problem 1 won't remain in problem 2. You can try to use your `x` from problem 1 as a initial guess for `y` in problem 2, but it is not guaranteed to reduce your searching time in optimization.

Yet a linear matrix equation solving is not that hard with the powerful packages. You can use [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) or [QR decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) to improve the computing efficiency very much.